# Add result to view with webservice

Tags: views, 8, commerce

In my drupal 8 Commerce, I have a view with product and filter criteria.

And I want to know, if it's possible to add result to this view with a result of webservice.

I try to inspect `$view->result in hook_views_pre_render`

and the result is `view\ResultRow` with `entity Product`

[image]

Is it possible to add results without creating an entity and from an webservice just read information like this schema:

**/myviewurl**

- Product 1 (from drupal db)
- Product 2 (from drupal db)
- Product 3 (from drupal db)
- Product 4 (from webservice not in db)
- Product 5 (from webservice not in db)
- Product 6 (from webservice not in db)

Answer (score 0):

Try **hook_views_pre_render** hook to alter view result if only you need to display result. You just need to prepare the webservice result as per **hook_views_pre_render** result data.